# Difference between local variable initialize null and not initialize?

Tags: java

In Java, what is the difference and best way to do?

```
Integer x = null; // x later assign some value.
Integer y; // y later initialize and use it.
```

Comment: The difference is that the compiler will prevent you from reading the uninitialized variable.

Comment: Depends if you want it to be initialised to `null` or if you want to make sure you have to initialise it later before you can use it.

Comment: This is really unclear. You've said "variable," do you really *mean* "variable"? The answer is very different for instance members, which some people loosely call "instance variables," than it is for actual variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer depends on what type of variable are you referring.

For *class variables*, there's no difference, see the [**JLS - 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> ... Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is
>   used:
>
> For all reference types ([§4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is `null`.

Meaning, there is no difference, the later is implicitly set to `null`.

If the variables are *local*, they must be assigned before you pass them to a method:

```
myMethod(x); //will compile :)
myMethod(y)  //won't compile :(
```

Answer (score 5):

Local variables must be assigned to something before they are used.

```
Integer x = null;
myFunction(x);
// myFunction is called with the argument null

Integer y;
myFunction(y);
// This will not compile because the variable has not been initialised
```

Class variables are always initialised to a default value (`null` for object types, something like zero for primitives) if you don't explicitly initialise them. Local variables are not implicitly initialised.

Answer (score 3):

Its better to not set it to null, otherwise you can by accident use it and cause NPE. Compiler wont help you with compile error. Only set to null if you want to have logic like if ( x != null ) { /*use it*/ }

Answer (score 2):

No difference at all. Both cases when ever you want to use it, local variable must be in initialized form(must have a value).

From `Java` doc

> Similar to how an object stores its state in fields, a method will
>   often store its temporary state in local variables. The syntax for
>   declaring a local variable is similar to declaring a field (for
>   example, int count = 0;). There is no special keyword designating a
>   variable as local; that determination comes entirely from the location
>   in which the variable is declared — which is between the opening and
>   closing braces of a method. As such, local variables are only visible
>   to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible
>   from the rest of the class.

Comment: There is a difference. If you have already set it to `null`, then you can pass `x` to a method as `null` without reassigning it. If you haven't assigned it at all, the compiler won't let you use it until you do.

Comment: @khelwood I am telling no difference in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Internally there is no difference. Also it is a debatable topic.

Use the local variable only if it is really required. Local variables are mostly in the following scenarios (I may be missing few other).

As a shorthand or for Readability

```
Integer myObject = someObject.someFunction().someOtherFunction();
```

If we use the syntax like that in many places, code will become clumsy.

For accessibility

```
Object returnObject = null;    
if(mycondition)
{
    returnObject = value1;
}
else if(secondCondition)
{
    returnObject = value2;
}

return returnObject;
```

The caller of the above code snippet will take decision based on the return value. 
Honestly speaking i am not seeing other valid use case to declare a variable without initial value.

Conclusion (Best Practice):

- Declare local variable only if required
- Always create local variable with default value.

Answer (score 1):

No differences at all expect for one thing, if you don't initialize it and later on you try to use this variable (without changing the reference) means an error at compilation time, but if you initialize it and you use it later on  (without changing the reference) means a NullPointerException.

I show you with an example.

**Without initializing**

```
Integer y;
y.intValue(); // Compilation error
```

**With initializing**

```
Integer x = null;
x.intValue(); // You are able to compile it but NullPointerException
```